# Solving inequality with `Reduce` doesn't work

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve an inequality in terms of one variable under some conditions for parameter. Here is the code.

```
Assuming[lm > 1 && 0 < u < 1 && rmax > 0 && iD > 0 && rmax > iD && iE > iD, FullSimplify@Reduce[(iE + rmax + lm rmax (-1 + u) - iD lm u)/(1 - lm) - iD > 0, lm]]
```

The code instructs to solve in terms of `lm` but the outcome is in terms if `iE`, which is as follows.

```
(iD - rmax) (1 + lm (-1 + u)) > iE
```

Do you know why?

**EDIT: `user64494`'s answer suggested below does not work either. To see this, consider the following inequality:

```
Assuming[(iD - rmax) (1 + lm (-1 + u)) > iE && lm > 1 + lm u && iE + rmax u < rmax + iD u && iE lm + rmax + lm rmax u < lm (rmax + iD u) && lm > 1 && 0 < u && u < 1 && rmax > 0 && iD > 0 && rmax > iD && rmax > iE && iE > iD, FullSimplify@Reduce[rmax/2 + iE > rmax + iE/(1 + lm (-1 + u)), rmax]]
```

whose outcome is

```
lm (2 iE - rmax) (-1 + u) < rmax
```

which is not exactly in terms of `rmax`. Now, following `user64494`'s approach:

```
Reduce[(iD - rmax) (1 + lm (-1 + u)) > iE && lm > 1 + lm u && iE + rmax u < rmax + iD u && iE lm + rmax + lm rmax u < lm (rmax + iD u) && lm > 1 && 0 < u && u < 1 && rmax > 0 && iD > 0 && rmax > iD && rmax > iE && iE > iD && rmax/2 + iE > rmax + iE/(1 + lm (-1 + u)), rmax]
```

whose outcome is

```
iE > 0 && 0 < iD < iE && 0 < u < iE/(-iD + 2 iE) && lm > -(1/(-1 + u)) && (-iE lm + iD lm u)/(1 - lm + lm u) < rmax < (-2 iE lm + 2 iE lm u)/(1 - lm + lm u)
```

from which I cannot immediately tell which one is the solution for the inequality I'm looking for.

Comment: Reduce[(iE + rmax + lm rmax (-1 + u) - iD lm u)/(1 - lm) - iD > 
  0, lm, Reals]

Comment: @csn899, I get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following works in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

```
Reduce[(iD - rmax) (1 + lm (-1 + u)) > iE && lm > 1 && 0 < u < 1 && 
rmax > 0 && iD > 0 && rmax > iD && iE > iD, lm]
```

> `rmax > 0 && 0 < iD < rmax && iE > iD && 0 < u < 1 &&  lm > (-iD + iE + rmax)/(-iD + rmax + iD u - rmax u)`

Addition.@ppp: Don't understand what you mean by "complete answer". The result can be rewritten  as `Piecewise[{{lm > (-iD + iE + rmax)/(-iD + rmax + iD u - rmax u),     lrmax > 0 && 0 < iD < rmax && iE > iD && 0 < u < 1}, {Null, True}}]`.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not provide a complete answer. I added why in my post in the edit. Can you please take a look and help me once more? Thanks!